# VB.Net Satisfy if condition from array BEFORE else statement executes

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

This is killing me because I know why it's doing it but I don't know how to stop it. I am reading from a text file where I have 2 users on 2 lines: bill|777 & john|333.
My conditional statement satisfies both conditions because when it loops thru, it declines one user and accepts the other causing it to do the if and the else. Please tell me how to do this one at a time. Loop thru the text, get the proper user and then go thru the conditions.

```
    Dim MyReader As New StreamReader("login.txt")

    While Not MyReader.EndOfStream
        Dim user As String = UsernameTextBox.Text + "|" + PasswordTextBox.Text
        Dim names() As String = MyReader.ReadLine().Split()
        For Each myName In names
            If user = myName Then
                Me.Hide()
                OrderForm.Show()

            Else
                MsgBox("Wrong username and password")
            End If
        Next
    End While
    MyReader.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
    Using MyReader As New StreamReader("login.txt")
        Dim GoodUser As Boolean = False
        Dim user As String = UsernameTextBox.Text + "|" + PasswordTextBox.Text
        While Not MyReader.EndOfStream
            Dim user As String = UsernameTextBox.Text + "|" + PasswordTextBox.Text
            Dim names() As String = MyReader.ReadLine().Split()
            If Not names Is Nothing Then
                For Each myName In names
                    If user = myName Then
                        GoodUser = True
                        Me.Hide()
                        OrderForm.Show()
                        Exit While
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End While
        If Not GoodUser Then
            MsgBox("Wrong username and password")
        End If
    End Using
```

The using block automatically disposes of the streamreader.  A boolean to signify a good login can set the condition when the While loop exits.  The Exit While will break out of the loop when the proper user is found.  It's usually a good idea to set a conditional to check for empty lines

One thing to watch for. If a user name includes a space your code won't work.  You'll have to either restrict the user names or use a different delimiter like `~`.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I have to study the If Not Names is Nothing and get a better understanding. I really appreciate it.

Comment: To simplify the if statement.  It basically means `if names is something`.  But because there isn't a value that means something we use the `Not` to reverse the value from `Is Nothing`. So if names is nothing then none of the code in the If block will run, but if it isn't nothing then the code will run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader("login.txt")

    Dim line As String = r.ReadLine
        Dim user As String = UsernameTextBox.Text + "|" + PasswordTextBox.Text
        Dim found As Boolean = False        

    Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
        If (line = user) Then
               found = True
               break
        End If  
        line = r.ReadLine
    Loop           
    If (Not found) Then
           MessageBox.Show("Wrong username and password")
    End If
End Using
```